# Inverse format function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there an inverse format function in SQL Server ?.

I have to import some datetime values as 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss' strings (example '20220406T123043' for the 06/04/2022 12:30:43), but I cannot convert easily to datetime those strings because I can't see such format (style) available for the CONVERT function.

So, is there a way to convert from string to datetime indicating a format mask ?.

It would be something like :

```
convert(datetime, '20220406T123043', 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss')
unformat('20220406T123043','yyyyMMddTHHmmss')
...
```

... or I have no other option than using datefromparts and extract each part using substrings ?.

Thank you.

Comment: `CONVERT` with a style code is what you want, just sometimes you need to manipulate the value to fit the style code you want; such as removing or adding characters in the right place. For example, the format `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss` (style `112`) is an unambiguous format; so you just need to replace (`REPLACE`) the `T` and inject (`STUFF`) the `:`s.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I didn't thought about insert the ":" with STUFF in order to convert the input strings to the 112 style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Larnu advice, I have replaced 'T' with an space, and injected ":" separators with the STUFF function, so the strings can now be converted to datetime using the 112 style.

```
convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(replace('20220406T123043','T',' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),112)
```

Thank you.